# Add Attribute Jquery data type string + variable

Tags: jquery

I have this variable called `vp_height` that I want to put as data variable, as putting it as this, it prompt an error.

```
var vp_height = viewportSize.getHeight();

//Sample Data
$(".carol").attr({
    "data-" + vp_height : "width:50%;"
});
```

Here's the error

[image]

it should look like this in the frontend. (visual presentation)

```
<div class="staff-container carol" data-667="width:50%;"></div>
```

Any solution to this stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(".carol").attr("data-" + vp_height, "width:50%;");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5N8ZM/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .attr() format that accepts a key and a value instead of one that accepts an object

```
$(".carol").attr("data-" + vp_height, "width:50%;");
```

---

If you want to create a object with variable keys then

```
var obj = {};
obj["data-" + vp_height] = "width:50%;";
$(".carol").attr(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.data()` method to set the data attribute:

```
$(".carol").data(vp_height, "width:50%;");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".carol").attr("data-" + vp_height, "width:50%;");
```